# Can we extract Envelope ID from DOCUSIGN Link

Tags: docusignapi

How can i find the envelope id from docusign link , https://na3.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=&er=&data=04|01||||0|0|637393960640614189|Unknown||1000&sdata==&reserved=0

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to extract it from such a link. Easiest way is to go to the envelope itself within the web console and click on "Envelope Id"